# Не работает JS. Не выводит <input value>

Tags: javascript

Застрял на элементарном, не могу понять почему так.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="test.js"></script>
   <script src = 
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<title>Test JS</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--<div id="test" onclick="$ ('#test').hide()">Test </div>-->
<input id="clmn1" type="text"  value= "10">
<input id="clmn2" type="text" value= "65" >
<input id="clmn3"  type="text"  value= "8" >
<button> Get Numb</button>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S JQuery здесь просто так. Этот проект для практики)

ну и вот сам JS

```
 var x = document.getElementById('clmn1');
 var y = x.value;
 alert(y);
```

Вроде бы все правильно, но я так и не пойму, почему оно не выводит окно.

Comment: ваш код выводит `alert` - какое окно вы хотите вывести?

Comment: суть в том, что оно alert и не выводит

Comment: ваш код выводит мне в alert значение input 1

Comment: странно, у меня только input и кнопка, а alert вообще нет

Comment: Ваш код сработает только один раз после загрузки окна браузера и обновления скрипта, вам лучше вывести кнопку, которая будет выводить вам alert

Comment: я думал оно "10" должно вывести, а на деле вообще ничего нет

Comment: добавил ответ, измените свой код - нажмите `alert` все будет работать по клику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
'use strict';

 var x = document.getElementById('clmn1');
  var y = x.value;
 $("#alert").on("click", function(){
  alert(y);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

   
<title>Test JS</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--<div id="test" onclick="$ ('#test').hide()">Test </div>-->
<input id="clmn1" type="text"  value= "10">
<input id="clmn2" type="text" value= "65" >
<input id="clmn3"  type="text"  value= "8" >
<button> Get Numb</button>
<button id="alert"> Alert </button>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```